# Trouble with Google MailApp html option

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am having trouble setting up a script to iterate through a Google spreadsheet and email to the employees the lines that contain the reports about them.

In my tests The email address and subject lines are being emailed but depending on what I try the email is either blank or says "[object Object]".

I am viewing emails from the Gmail site in Chrome.

The HTML code does not have any variables yet. I am still working on getting it to email correctly and then I will try working in scriplets to build a table for the report.

Code.gs

```
function changeName() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shA = ss.getSheets()[0];    // Report download
  var shB = ss.getSheets()[1];    // Names & email address
  var alRow = shA.getLastRow();
  var blRow = shB.getLastRow();
  var data = shA.getRange(1, 1, alRow, 14).getValues();    // Array of all employees reports
  var employees = shB.getRange(1, 1, 2, 2).getValues();    // List of employees [i][0] and email address [i][1] in Scorecard data
  for(i=0;i<employees.length;i++){
    var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
    MailApp.sendEmail(employees[i][1], employees[i][0] + ' Scorecards Test', {htmlbody: html.getContent()});
    Logger.log(html.getContent());
  }
}
```

Index.html

```
<body>
<p1>Test 5062</p1>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Test Cell 1</td>
<td>Test Cell 2</td>
<td>Test Cell 3</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
```

When I view the log, it shows the HTML file.

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a following modification?

#### From :

```
function changeName() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shA = ss.getSheets()[0];    // Report download
  var shB = ss.getSheets()[1];    // Names & email address
  var alRow = shA.getLastRow();
  var blRow = shB.getLastRow();
  var data = shA.getRange(1, 1, alRow, 14).getValues();    // Array of all employees reports
  var employees = shB.getRange(1, 1, 2, 2).getValues();    // List of employees [i][0] and email address [i][1] in Scorecard data
  for(i=0;i<employees.length;i++){
    var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
    MailApp.sendEmail(employees[i][1], employees[i][0] + ' Scorecards Test', {htmlbody: html.getContent()});
    Logger.log(html.getContent());
  }
}
```

#### To :

```
function changeName() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shA = ss.getSheets()[0];    // Report download
  var shB = ss.getSheets()[1];    // Names & email address
  var alRow = shA.getLastRow();
  var blRow = shB.getLastRow();
  var data = shA.getRange(1, 1, alRow, 14).getValues();    // Array of all employees reports
  var employees = shB.getRange(1, 1, 2, 2).getValues();    // List of employees [i][0] and email address [i][1] in Scorecard data
  for(i=0;i<employees.length;i++){
    var html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: employees[i][1],
      subject: employees[i][0] + ' Scorecards Test',
      htmlBody: html.getContent()
    });
    Logger.log(html.getContent());
  }
}
```

If this didn't work, I'm sorry.

Comment: If I understand the documentation correctly, I was using the standard way of passing the email address and subject to the function and you method skips them and uses the advanced options to pass email address, subject and html on the function. Either should work. I will try you method and see what I can learn

Comment: Not sure I understand why it did not work when I tried it before or why my posted code did not work but your code worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @CRB Welcome. Thank you, too. I'm glad I could be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

I find it a lot easier to build the html right in the file like this:

```
var s='<table>';
s+='Utilities.formatString('<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>',data[i][0],data[i][1],data[i][2]);
s+='</table>'`;
MailApp.sendMail({to:emailAddress, subject: subj, htmlBody: s});
```

And keep in mind your html doesn't have to be complete.

Often I actually build the email this way and disable the sendEmail while I'm building it and just do this to view my results.

```
var ui=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s);
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModeLessDialog(ui,title);
```

And that way I can see what I'm doing while I built it without having to send emails.  Some people use the logger but I like doing it this way.

And often people end up wanting to put some conditions on sending the email.

1. Email Address is not empty
2. Body is not empty
3. The email hasn't already been sent
4. You haven't exceeded your remaining daily quota

But hey everyone is different and you can choose to do it whatever way that makes you happy.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Quite a few good tips in there, especially the ui suggestion.

Comment: I play around with building the html in the code and in a separate html file. The reason I was going with separate files was that I seemed easier to format my html for readability in the html page. Rather then having to break strings up in the code page. Do you think that is a common issue or something to learn to work with?

Comment: A lot of people use template files.  I don't, I find it easy to wind it together with code, probably because I don't plan what I'm going to do until I started coding.